# using styles from './page.less' React

Tags: reactjs, less

What I am trying to do:

```
import styles from './page.less';

<div className={styles.header}></div>
```

this is my webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
  })],
};
```

I have install the less and less loader dependency, but it is still not able to use the styling from page.less, where did I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `import` statement:

```js
import './page.less'

<div className="header"></div>
```

Suppose you have these styles

```
// page.less

.header {
  // some styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found you need to wrap your loaders into a single object notation

```
 {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                { loader: 'css-loader' },
                { loader: 'less-loader' }
            ]
        }
```

I think it will work. :)

Comment: this will allow me to use this ```import styles from './page.less';``` ?? . I tried and it is not

Comment: @yongchang Keep import styles from './page.less'; as it is just change the loaders object notation , it is missing in your webpack.config.js file , the  { loader: 'style-loader' }, should be like this and not to be like     use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],

Comment: keeping ``` import styles from './page.less'; ``` does not apply the styling :(, I have tried

Comment: @yongchang You need to change   use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],

Comment: use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                { loader: 'css-loader' },
                { loader: 'less-loader' }
            ]

Comment: this is my repo link https://github.com/lieyongchang/RepoWIthIssue.git , i tried various way and it does not work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240921/discussion-between-yongchang-and-pranavjeet-mishra).